# Is Unix "permission model" conceptually broken?

Tags: permissions, security, privacy

Suppose a teacher has prepared for his students, before course's beginning, a series of surprise tests that cover it whole.

```
tests
├── subject1
│   └── exam.txt
├── subject2
│   └── exam.txt
├── subject3
│   └── exam.txt
└── subject4
    └── exam.txt
```

Let's say he puts the `tests` directory in each student's computer user home.

Then he recursively sets the following permissions

```
owner: teacher
group: teachers
mode: 550
```

on the `tests` directory, so that only other teachers *can read the subjects* and also access exam texts.

At the end of the first semester, he thinks his students are ready for the first
trial and so the night before he sets

```
owner: teacher
group: teachers
mode: 771
```

on the `tests` directory and

```
owner: student
group: teachers
mode: 770
```

on the `subject1` subdirectory, so that next day the students will be able
to access the test *only after he will have told them the path*.

Then the following morning he discovers the students not only have already
read the test, but they even know *all the subjects*, because they had
leveraged the fact that the system tells them when they are trying to access
a non-existing directory and when they are trying to access an existing directory
they *eventually* don't have read permissions on, so they brute-forced `tests`
using `ls` and a dictionary.

Clearly the teacher has been naive in thinking the students won't have tried to access
the text before the exam; neverthless my questions are:

*what's the point of not giving *read* permissions on a directory
if the user can still brute force the name of each object in it?*

*Why doesn't the system just return a generic error whenever the user is trying to access something he shouldn't had access to in the first place?*

Comment: It is not related to permissions issues, but on method issues here. The approach of the problem/organization,  just a mess out of sens in my opinion. Never a teacher directory have to be changed (*permissions*) it just has to be copied or linked on the pertinent date to students work directories. Or better, students just pull exercises/tests from a git repo opened special for the test/exam on the chosen date. *(here teachers have permissions on gitlab of course)* etc...etc....  there are so many methods & tools to do that, no **ready-to-give** answer is really possible.

Comment: 1st question : you just don't understand the unix permissions, it just does what it has to do in current description of the issue. 2cd one : for the same reason, in fact it is not a second error bet consequence of the 1st one.

Comment: The issue is primarily the fact that the teacher manages files in the students' home directories. That should not be possible on any sanely set up system (where teachers are not admins), and is totally unnecessary for the purpose of what the teacher(s) are trying to do.  Why manage more than a single copy of the tests? What if students already have directories with the same names (e.g. `~/tests`)?

Comment: Pretty sure "so that next day the students will be able to access the test only after he will have told them the path" means you'd need to set 110 permissions on `subject1`, not 660.

Comment: More general view: for each permission bit you can find a scenario where this bit is useful; still some *combinations* of permissions may make little or no sense. Just don't use these exact combinations. Similarly some *sequences* of bytes are invalid in Unicode, so they shouldn't appear in Unicode text. If you deliberately create such a sequence and interpret as Unicode, it's your problem. If anyone sets permissions that make no sense, it's their problem.

Comment: to @francoisP and "they" (can't tag more than one user): I'm not judging nor what the teacher has done nor his reasons here; the example is just an ad-hoc plot device made to show that *not being able to read but being able to transverse* doesn't imply *not being able to know what there is in the directory* and that a more coherent behaviour would be to just say no to everything, like when you try to connect to an ssh host you don't have credentials for.

Comment: Intuitively one is brought to think that *not being able to read* is the same as covering your eyes and that *being able to transverse* is the same as to be given the exit path to a labyrinth, while reality is that the combination of the two is *you're free to roam in a dark room and touch everything*.

Comment: @nog642 nah, I meant the teacher setup the directories for the test. With 110 they couldn't read nor edit it.

Comment: Your scenario is broken, not unix permissions.   Also, you should never use 6 as a permission on a directory.  +r,-x makes very little sense on a directory.  +w,-x makes no sense.

Comment: Setting `r` or `rw` permission on a directory makes no sense without `x`. You should have either (a) no access, or (b) `x` optionally with other permission bits

Comment: @roaima You might want to allow someone to know when a certain file is available without allowing access to the file. By taking away `x` you can enforce that access is not possible no matter what the creator of the file does to its permissions.

Comment: @HaukeLaging `+rx` or `-rx` would still make more sense IMO. Without `x` on a directory it doesn't matter whether a file exists or not; I still can't get to it. `mkdir x; touch x/y; chmod a-x x` now we can `cat x/y` or `cat x/z` and in both cases we still get `permission denied`

Comment: @Scrooge "intuitively" Intuition sucks. Use your reason, not your intuition. Don't add the the `x` permission for everybody  to a directory if you don't want to let everybody access the files within it.

Comment: "Is X broken?" for models can often be answered with "It's not broken, it's *limited*." What's important is knowing the limitations and then either reworking the situation to fit them or using another model. The answerable question is: "Is model X usable for scenario Y?" Is Newtonian physics broken? It works well enough for a lot of things outside relativistic scenarios. Is the use of Euclidean geometry in the real world broken? It works well enough when spacetime curvature isn't significant enough to be relevant. Is the POSIX permissions model broken? Works well enough for a lot of use cases.

Comment: This post reads more like it's trying to prove a point already decided, and less like a genuine question. There's one situation, which honestly looks tailor-made to prove how the permission model is wrong. No comparison to other situations, no consideration on if the same goals could be achieved by other means. (like just copying the files to the student-accessible directory when they should get to see the file, or using email, or...). It's a bit like asking if knives are useless since yours doesn't cut and your hand hurts when using it, but neglecting to think about holding it the right way.

Comment: @ilkkachu the question needs to be rephrased to better reflect what I find counterintuitive on the euristic verbal description of the permissions.

Answer (score -3):

No, the Unix/Linux "permission model" is not "broken", your scenario is.
Unix/Linux is a powerful set of tools, but it does not prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot.